# How do I dynamically insert html table cell data into a table with dynamic headers in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm creating a `<table>` with `React 0.14.6` that has a series of column headers that are dynamically  inserted into a `<thead>` of a `<table>`:

`CourseTable.js`:

```
import CourseList from './CourseList';
import GradesHeader from './GradesHeader';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class CourseTable extends Component {
  /**
   * Gets all unique terms that have grades
   * @param courses {Array}
   * @return {Array}
   */
  getUniqueTerms(courses) {
    let uniqueTerms = [];
    courses.forEach(course => {
      if (course.grades) {
        Object.keys(course.grades).forEach(term => {
          if (uniqueTerms.indexOf(term) === -1) {
            uniqueTerms.push(term);
          }
        })
      }
    });
    return uniqueTerms;
  }

  createGradesHeaders(courses) {
    return this.getUniqueTerms(courses).map(term => {
      return (
        <th>
          <GradesHeader headerText={term}/>
        </th>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    let headers = this.createGradesHeaders(this.props.courses);
    return (
      <table className="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Period
          </th>
          <th>
            Class
          </th>
          <th>
            Term
          </th>
          <th>
            Date Enrolled
          </th>
          <th>
            Date Left
          </th>
          <th>
            <div>Absenses</div>
            <div>All (Excused)</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Tardies
          </th>
          <th></th>
          {headers}
          <th>
            Teacher
          </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <CourseList courseData={this.props.courses}/>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

`GradesHeader.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class GradesHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.headerText}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`Course.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Course extends Component {
  render() {
    const unexcused = !!this.props.courseData.attendance.unexcused ? this.props.courseData.attendance.unexcused : 0;
    const excused = !!this.props.courseData.attendance.excused ? this.props.courseData.attendance.excused : 0;
    const totalAbsences = unexcused + excused;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          {this.props.courseData.expression}
        </td>
        <td>
          {this.props.courseData.course_name}
        </td>
        <td>
          {this.props.courseData.abbreviation}
        </td>
        <td>
          {this.props.courseData.dateenrolled}
        </td>
        <td>
          {this.props.courseData.dateleft}
        </td>
        <td>
          {totalAbsences}
          ({excused})
        </td>
          // Grades for this course go here
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          {this.props.courseData.lastfirst}
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

You can see in `CourseTable.js` where I'm dynamically generating the headers for this section of the table's `<thead>`. I'm confused on how to insert/pidgeonhole the data for each grade into the corresponding column.

I think I need to somehow identify each of the `<th>` header elements that are dynamically generated, and reference those when I insert into those columns, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: So since React re-renders after a state change, what you're going to want to do is add the new row to the state and then pass it down to the component to render to the virtual DOM. The virtual DOM will then figure out what's changed and make the changes accordingly to the real DOM.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you're suggesting? I'm having trouble coming to a working solution solely from your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, as mentioned in a comment, use states. States are pretty useful. [ReactJS states](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) If  you want to pidgeonhole new headers you could assign them with an ID, so that you could cycle through them correctly when rendering a new. As mentioned, react re-renders on state change. There are a few examples of this in facebooks tutorial page and also in the documentation.

Say you gather all your headers in an object, or perhaps they are coming from a database.

```
var headers = [{id: 0, name: grade}
               {id: 1, name: term}
]
```

So in your render method of heads you can put them in like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        headers: headers,
    }
},

sortAlg(arr) {
    //Choose one, make one
},

render() {
this.sortAlg(this.state.headers);
var headerArr = [];
headers.forEach(function(header) {
    headerArr.push(<YourHeader header = {header} />
});
return (
  <table className="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        {headerArr}
    </thead>
    <CourseList courseData={this.props.courses}/>
  </table>
);
```

The `<YourHeader />` is a component you make for better control. How I like doing it, atleast.

I hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well the question and your data structure, you could pass the grades computed with `getUniqueTerms` to your `CourseList` component.

So in `CourseTable.js` :

```
render() {
    let grades = this.uniqueTerms(this.props.courses);
    let headers = this.createGradesHeaders(grades);
    // and then in your jsx
    <CourseList courseData={ this.props.courses } grades={ grades } />
}
```

And in the `render` method of your `Course` component :

```
{
    this.props.grades.map( grade =>
        <td key={ grade }>
            // whatever data you need to print from this.props.courseData.grades[grade]
        </td>
    )
}
```

Hope it helps!